# Source not found - RouteProvider not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-4.5

I'm seeing a typical issue.

From Register custom routes, I'm calling controller method like this:

```
 protected override void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection rots, IProuteProvider rotProvider)
    {
     rotProvider.MapRoute(rots,null, "SignIn",new {Controller = "Layout", Action = "SignIn"});
     ----------
     ----------
    }
```

I have controller class present with the method in the same project.

However, when I'm trying to go inside the controller by "F11". Its showing be error, in another page/file "Source not found"

```
  RouteProvider.cs not found.

   You need to find RouteProvider.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame.
```

I think, this is due to custom route. Ideally, as the controller source code is present in the same solution/project, it should route to correct controller method. But, way its not happening?

Is there any way to point that to controller method for debug?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Class called as CustomRouteConstraint which will implement IRouteConstraint interface which will be like this

```
public class CustomRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Register Custom Route Constraints in RouteConfig as

```
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        var constraintsResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintsResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("CustomRoute", typeof(CustomRouteConstraint));
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(constraintsResolver);
```

Now use that in your Controller as

```
[Route("MvcTest/other/{name:CustomRoute}")]

public ActionResult OtherPage(string name)

{

    return View();

}
```